# Using Android APK Expansion Downloader with NativeActivity

Tags: android, android-ndk

I have a fully native application that works nicely right now. Only Java code that I used is a subclass of NativeActivity which I use to load some dynamic libraries like this:

```
public class MyNativeActivity extends NativeActivity
{
    static
    {
        System.loadLibrary("anexternallib");
        System.loadLibrary("mynativelib");
    }
}
```

I'm using .obb files by mounting them from native code for some data and it seems I have to consider some cases like when the user deletes or renames the '.obb' etc. Google provides a library for this(Google Play APK Expansion Library) but implementing 'IDownloaderClient' with my NativeActivity generates a black screen and creates 'not responding' error. Creating a new non-native Activity and adding it to my AndroidManifest.xml seems to work for a few seconds but my app freezes after then. What is the correct way to do this?